# Unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've followed multiple stack overflow posts regarding this same issue, but I don't think I have the rails proficiency to know how to apply these fixes to my code.

Been following an old railscast show: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

And I'm aware that the issue is something to do with permitting objects/hashes but I just don't understand it all.

The error I'm getting is from this line of code in my controller:

```
session[:zerch_params].deep_merge!(params[:zerch]) if params[:zerch]
```

**Controller**
class ZerchesController < InheritedResources::Base

```
def index
    @zerches = Zerch.all
end

def show
    @zerch = Zerch.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    session[:zerch_params] ||= {}
    @zerch = Zerch.new(session[:zerch_params])
    @zerch.current_step = session[:zerch_step]
end

def create
    session[:zerch_params].deep_merge!(params[:zerch]) if params[:zerch]
    @zerch = Zerch.new(session[:zerch_params])
    @zerch.current_step = session[:zerch_step]
    if @zerch.valid?
        if params[:back_button]
            @zerch.previous_step
        elsif @zerch.last_step?
            @zerch.save if @zerch.all_valid?
        else            
            @zerch.next_step
        end
        session[:zerch_step] = @zerch.current_step
end
if @zerch.new_record?
    render "new"
else
    session[:zerch_step] = session[:zerch_params] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "zerch complete!"
    redirect_to @zerch
end
end




private

def zerch_params
  params.require(:zerch).permit(:location, :category, :price)
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this from the model and in the controller:

I still had

```
attr_accessor
```

while also having `params` in `private`. I removed this, and also in the controller I changed the line of code from this:

```
session[:zerch_params].deep_merge!(params[:zerch]) if params[:zerch]
```

to this:

```
session[:zerch_params].deep_merge!(params.permit![:zerch]) if params[:zerch]
```